# How to set up Jenkins Pipeline trigger on commit to Github SCM private repo?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, pipeline, polling

I want to setup a Github webhook trigger to start the pipeline as soon as the commit is triggered.
I've done the usual and set up webhook to `http://Jenkins URL:port/github-webhook/` but it doesn't seem to work.
I've also added the repo in Github repo field in the configuration part of the pipeline job.

What other settings do I need to set to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable some logging to have more information about what is really happening.

Go to "Manage Jenkins" -> "System Log" -> "Add new log recorder" and give it a name then add the 3 following loggers:

- com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger
- org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.WebhookManager
- com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubWebHook

Now you can click "Test hook" on the Github UI and check what is in the log.
If there's nothing that obviously means that Github cannot reach your Jenkins instance but I guess if that's the case Github should be warning you that the trigger do not work well.